# Parsing Strings from json in Python

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I am parsing a JSON document in Python and I have gotten nearly the whole process to work except I am having trouble converting a GPS string into the correct form.

I have the following form:

```
"gsx$gps":{"$t":"44°21′N 68°13′W\ufeff / \ufeff44.35°N 68.21°W\ufeff / 44.35; -68.21\ufeff (Acadia)"}
```

and that is from this HTML form:

```
44°21′N 68°13′W / 44.35°N 68.21°W / 44.35; -68.21 (Acadia)
```

and I want the final product to be a string that looks like this:

```
(44.35, -68.21)
```

here are a few other example JSON strings just to give you some more to work with:

```
"gsx$gps":{"$t":"14°15′S 170°41′W\ufeff / \ufeff14.25°S 170.68°W\ufeff / -14.25; -170.68\ufeff (American Samoa)"}

"gsx$gps":{"$t":"38°41′N 109°34′W\ufeff / \ufeff38.68°N 109.57°W\ufeff / 38.68; -109.57\ufeff (Arches)"}
```

I have the following:

```
GPSlocation = entry['gsx$gps']['$t']
```

and then I don't know how to get GPSlocation into the form that I want above.

Comment: this isnt parsing json ... he already has a json built dict... its just parsing the format above to a tuple ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not super elegant but it works...also you are not parsing json ... just parsing a string...

```
import re
center_part = GPSLocation.split("/")[1]
N,W = centerpart.split()
N,W = N.split("\xb0")[0],W.split("\xb0")[0]
tpl = (N,W)
print tpl
```

on a side note these are not ints ...

Comment: alright great. yes I am just parsing a string. this gives me what I need but what exactly is the \xb0 signifying?

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
import json
jstr = """{"gsx$gps":{"$t":"14°15′S 170°41′W\ufeff / \ufeff14.25°S 170.68°W\ufeff / -14.25; -170.68\ufeff (American Samoa)"}}"""
a = json.loads(jstr)
tuple(float(x) for x in a['gsx$gps']['$t'].split('/')[-1].split(u'\ufeff')[0].split(';'))
```

Gives:

```
(-14.25, -170.68)
```

Or from the plain string:

```
GPSlocation = u"14°15′S 170°41′W\ufeff / \ufeff14.25°S 170.68°W\ufeff / -14.25; -170.68\ufeff (American Samoa)"
tuple(float(x) for x in GPSlocation.split('/')[-1].split(u'\ufeff')[0].split(';'))
```

Some timeit fancy, why to avoid fancy regexp ;)

```
import re
import timeit
setup='GPSlocation = u"14°15′S 170°41′W\ufeff / \ufeff14.25°S 170.68°W\ufeff / -14.25; -170.68\ufeff (American Samoa)"; import re'
print timeit.timeit("map(float, GPSlocation.split('/')[-1].split(u'\ufeff')[0].split(';'))", setup=setup)
print timeit.timeit("map(float, re.findall(r'(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', GPSlocation)[-2:])", setup=setup)

5.89355301857
22.6919388771
```

Comment: with GPSlocation all I have is this string:  "14°15′S 170°41′W\ufeff / \ufeff14.25°S 170.68°W\ufeff / -14.25; -170.68\ufeff (American Samoa)" but I suppose if I go back a step this works

Comment: Just ignore the first two lines and replace `a['gsx$gps']['$t']` with `GPSlocation`.

Comment: the only problem I am having which I was having originally is that it isn't doing anything about the degree symbol and it cannot encode that

Comment: Well, you have to enable unicode. Also remember the little `u'asdf'` in front of the strings. How you import the unicode string correctly depends on your data source. `json.loads` creates unicode automatically for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data with regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '''"gsx$gps":{"$t":"44?21?N 68?13?W\ufeff / \ufeff44.35?N 68.21?W\ufeff / 44.35; -68.21\ufeff (Acadia)"}'''
>>> map(float, re.findall(r'(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', text)[-2:])
[44.35, -68.21]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r'.+/ (-?\d{1,3}\.\d\d); (-?\d{1,3}\.\d\d)\\.+',
       "(\g<1>, \g<2>)",
       "44°21′N 68°13′W\ufeff / \ufeff44.35°N 68.21°W\ufeff / 44.35; -68.21\ufeff (Acadia)")
```

Comment: This seems to have some issues, when you feed in unicode strings. Besides that, I don't think that the idea was, to output the values as string, but to get a tuple, where you can actually work with.